# Are there other ways to save data to cloud in Flutter other than firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

Are there other ways to save data in the cloud (sharing files such as pdf and others) other than using firebase?

Comment: First off, **exactly** what do you mean by "the cloud"? Please be as technical as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ObjectBox (NoSQL) is an another option for you.

here's the link : https://objectbox.io/

There are few more cloud options to opt, but FireStore and ObjectBox will give you more stability and flexibility in Flutter.

Comment: ObjectBox is highly recommend for High-performance. It is a NoSQL database with integrated Data Sync for decentralized Edge Computing. And it's available across Embedded Devices, IoT, and Mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is developed by Google and so is Firebase (as you probably know). Therefore most people use Firebase or Firestore if they want Cloud-based data persistence in their app as it is therefore the easiest and most effective way to (probably).

I have also used AWS Amplify, which can also be used as the cloud backend [(see this video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3IL20dedVc). And  you can use [Azure](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/9g393t/using_azure_app_services_with_flutter/) if you really want to. As mentioned in the replies, you need to be more technical with your question and define what you want to do.